# Which HTML tags are supported in Swing components?

Tags: java, html, swing

Many Swing components support embedded HTML, but I cannot find any official documentation on that subject. (Everything on Sun's pages about HTML seems to be targeted at JEditorPane)

So: Which HTML tags are supported in Swing components?

**EDIT:** Although I said that I'm missing "official documentation", I'd also like any "unofficial" documentation.

Comment: As with most things with Swing, the best course of action is to look at the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swing supports HTML 3.2 (Wilbur) as Software Monkey said. You can find official documentation to this obsolescent (1996) version of HTML at: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html

Java 7 documentation on the topic: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/package-summary.html

Though it is worth of noting that it does not explicitly mention this information is valid for other Swing components.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a narrow subset of HTML 3.x, although off the top of my head, I don't remember where I read that.

Comment: The Swing text component supports HTML 3.2 (Wilbur) and a reasonable subset of CSS 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what tags are supported, but I would suggest that you restrict yourself to bold/italics (or even better strong/em assuming it supports them) and img tags. Anything else is likely to cause headaches, and probably means you're stuffing too much into that component.

Comment: I don't think so - I'm saying that although it probably "supports" more - it's unlikely to support it well, and I've made a suggestion as to what the real issue might be.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer, I found this question through searching because I had the same question, and I think Draemon brings up a good point- "Anything else... probably means you're stuffing too much into that component."

Comment: You can do fancier stuff that just bold/italic.  I once created a JLabel with an HTML table, and stuffed it into a JScrollPane, and the only hack I needed to get this to work pretty well was a custom scroll increment.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mr.Napik notes in his answer, Swing HTML support was based on HTML 3.2, but it does support a few additional tags (notably `<span>`). The specific supported tags are documented in the [`HTML.Tag` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/html/HTML.Tag.html).

CSS support is also detailed in the [`CSS` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html).

Answer (score 1):

In fact Javax Swing HTML parser is a DTD driven parser.
The default DTD is called html32.dtd, meaning it supports most of HTML 32 recommendations.

If you want to support more Tags, you have to extend or rewrite this DTD.
For example, below, MathML support was added to Swing HTML :

[image]

A bug report was submitted to make this easier :
[Add Reference or Informations About DTDBuilder in Documentation](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8289722)

Beware :

- This is the first step to support your tag. Next, you had to design its rendering and register it in the View factory.
- Swing Text HTML is not for read HTML documents from the World Wide Web.
- Web Browsers don't use DTD approach.
- DTD approach makes sens if you want to have a strict control of your document structure in a project with the ability to export to World Wide Web but without the need to read real World HTML Documents. The DTD may stuck with malformed documents.
- Think of Swing HTML as a Wordpad where underlying document structure is HTML.