# JEditorPane doesn't want to show a button done in html (it shows in a browser)

Tags: java, html, button, jeditorpane

I created a buttton in html and linked it to another html file, when i open the file with the button in a browser (tried IE and FFox) the button shows and works properly, however when i   JEditorPane.setPage(the html file with the button) the only thing that shows is the name of the button with no actual clickable area or anything! Any ideas on how i can get the button to appear inside the pane?

Here's a pic of the button in the java frame(button is circled in red)
http://tinypic.com/r/fopswo/6

Here's a pic of the button in a browser(it's a button)
http://tinypic.com/r/2zjj71z/6

The code for the button

```
<font size = 12 face = "verdana" ><u> Creating An Account   </u></font> 
<span style="padding-left:360px"> </span>
<button onclick="window.location.href ='file:///F:/java 12/Isp/help file try/doc 2/test.html'">Back</button>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Swing's HTML support is patchy - I think you have fallen in one of its holes. More info here:

[Which HTML tags are supported in Swing components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872871/which-html-tags-are-supported-in-swing-components)