# How do you display two DIV's on the same line in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

I'm having difficulty aligning two divs on the same horizontal line within a JTextPane. I can do it in a number of different ways using normal HTML (rendered in my browser) but the same HTML never works in my JTextPane. Why?

### Here's what I have:

```
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
tp.setContentType("text/html");
tp.setText("<html><div style='float:left;border: 2px solid #555;padding:1px 5px;width:70px'>test</div><div style='float:right;border: 2px solid #555;padding:1px 5px;width:70px'>test2</div></html>");
```

### Here's what I want (browser render):

[image: Good browser render]

### Here's what I get (java app render):

[image: Bad java render]

Comment: Swing's support for HTML and CSS is limited, you may have stumbled on on of this limitions - for more information you might try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872871/which-html-tags-are-supported-in-swing-components)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Using that info (i.e., learning the HTML spec was so old) I just switched to tables which I know tended to be more supported way back.

Comment: Now it's a bit annoying, but Swing was among the first (that I know of) GUI API's to support HTML rendering as part of it's core API (you can use HTML within `JLabel` for example). Do wish they would update it...

Answer (score 1):

Given @[MadProgrammers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) comment regarding the HTML spec used (an old one), I created a work-around using tables instead. It seems if you make 3 table cells (`<td>`) and keep the middle one empty while assigning it an arbitrarily large width, it will push the right-most cell to the edge of the component area. The other cells needn't have their width's specified and they will still stretch appropriately to fit their content.

### Code:

```
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
tp.setContentType("text/html");
tp.setText("<html><table><tr><td><div style='border: 2px solid #555'>test</div></td><td width='999px'></td><td><div style='border: 2px solid #555'>test2</div></td></tr></table></html>");
```

### Result:

[image: html workaround]