# Rendering of colored listbox text using HTML in deployed application

Tags: html, matlab, listbox, matlab-deployment

**Context**

I'm building a GUI that I plan to deploy. In the GUI there are listboxes in which I want the text to be of different colors.

I found how to do it using HTML code, as an undocumented feature,  [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents/). Basically the code, copied/pasted from Yair's website, looks as follows.

```
uicontrol('Style','list', 'Position',[10,10,70,70], 'String', ...
{'<HTML><FONT color="red">Hello</Font></html>', 'world', ...
 '<html><font style="font-family:impact;color:green"><i>What a', ...
 '<Html><FONT color="blue" face="Comic Sans MS">nice day!</font>'});
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

Of course for my GUI the text would be different but the idea is the same, and I would use this feature on popup menus as well.

**Question**

Will this functionality be properly rendered in the deployed application or is it a risky business to use such HTML code? Note that I have no knowledge whatsoever of HTML so I don't know if it's trivial or not.

Of course an answer could be "Well just try it out and see the result" but I'd like to understand what is going on in the optics of using more HTML-based features in deployed applications.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to deploy it this way?

Comment: Not yet since I'm waiting for other things to get going about the application which are out of my control, but I'll try to as soon as possible. It's kind of dumb from me to ask this question before having tried deploying it, but I wanted to know if there were obvious/known caveats in using HTML in deployed code before heavily using it for my application.

Comment: There is no way to know since `uicontrol()` is a builtin function and the engine that deploys is also not public source. So, the only way to go about it is to test each single feature on a minimal deployed gui. I do not expect there to be a problem since the string should be considered as a static attribute.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input @OlegKomarov that is what I feared (relatively of course). If you want you can post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd wait a bit to see if someone is willing to show some test cases.

Comment: @Benoit_11: short answer: yes it's safe, as safe as you can use HTML in Java Swing components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this feature for many years in Matlab and in my compiled applications (includes commercial apps) - I've never noticed any difference in the uicontrols using HTML between Matlab and the deployed APP.

So yes it is safe to use!

Comment: Great thanks! I took a look at your website a while ago that's very nice stuff!

Comment: Thanks!!  :) I think it shows that you can easily make advanced and nice looking GUI's with Matlab!!

Comment: Yes indeed! I saw that you were using Python as well; do you use it quite a lot for complex GUIs or you rely entirely on MATLAB/another language?

Comment: Recently I have been focusing all my efforts on Matlab (core + Java) - hence the development of the Matlab GUI Toolbox.  I have also used wxPython and QT over the years, Visual Studio C++.  In reality it depends on the client/project...

Answer (score 2):

While not fully answering your question, from a HTML point of view, i can tell you right now that the `<font>` tag you are using is deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Consider using the paragraph tag: `<p>`

Comment: while that is true for modern web development, it's not the case for Java Swing components (that UICONTROLS are based on) which only support a subset of the now ancient HTML 3.2. So `<font>` is not deprecated there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/872871/97160. In fact you don't even have to close tags