# Why is font-size ignored when passing an HTML to the html component (hc:html)?

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports, font-size

We are building a report feature on our application, in which we pass through a html into a jasper to export it to pdf.

We have ran into a problem where the font-size specified in the HTML code doesn't get "read" by the jasper exporter, and the more content we have, the smaller the report gets.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Arial;
            color: #222222;
            background: #F4F0E8;
            font-size:9.0pt;
        }
        .Izquierda{
            float:left;
        }
        .Derecha{
            float:right;
        }
        .CabeceraInicio{
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        .filaN1{
            margin-top: 2px;
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 14px;
            font-size:9.0pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom:2px;
        }
        div.CabeceraInicio,a {
            color: #000033;
        }
        .infoTarea{
            font-size:9.0pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:#000033;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .TextoDescripcion{
            width: 90px;
            color: #777777;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-size:9.0pt;
            line-height: 17px;
        }
        div.pie {
            font-size:7.0pt;
            color: #777777;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .solucion {
            margin-left:30px;
            /*padding-left:5px;*/
            /*border-left: thin solid grey;*/
        }
        .nuevasComunicaciones{
            color: brown;
            margin-left:8px;
        }

/*          } */
/*      @media print{ */
/*          a:after{content:" (" attr(href) ") ";font-size:0.8em;font-weight:normal;} */
/*      } */

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="CabeceraInicio">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                        GT <a rel="nofollow" href='http://*IPIntranet*:8080/StsPyme/Pyme/IncidenciasyTareas/SeguimientoIncidencias/MaestroTareasMail.zul?start=yes&emp=*Empresa*&idtarea=*Codigo*&ip=*ip*&cuenta=*cuenta*'>_Acceso *TipoTarea* _Intranet</a>
            <!-- http://*IPIntranet*:8080/StsWeb/Pyme/IncidenciasyTareas/SeguimientoIncidencias/MaestroTareas.zul?start=yes&emp=*Empresa*&idtarea=*Codigo* -->
<!--                GT <a href='http://*IPIntranet*:8080/StsWeb/Pyme/IncidenciasyTareas/SeguimientoIncidencias/SeguimientoTareas.zul'>_Acceso *TipoTarea* _Intranet</a> -->
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">
                        <a href='http://*IPInternet*:8080/StsPyme/Pyme/IncidenciasyTareas/SeguimientoIncidencias/MaestroTareasMail.zul?start=yes&emp=*Empresa*&idtarea=*Codigo*&ip=*ip*&cuenta=*cuenta*'>_Acceso *TipoTarea* _Internet</a>
<!--                <a href='http://*IPInternet*:8080/StsWeb/Pyme/IncidenciasyTareas/SeguimientoIncidencias/SeguimientoTareas.zul'>_Acceso *TipoTarea* _Internet</a> -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br/>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="filaN1 infoTarea">*Accion* *TipoTarea* *FechaAccion* *DiaSemana* *HoraAccion* *NombreUsuarioAccion*</span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <span class="filaN1 infoTarea ">*NombreEmpresa*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<br/>
<div class="Izquierda" style="font-weight: bold;">
    *EstadoTarea*
</div>
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="infoTarea">
            _Informacion *TipoTarea*
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <span class="TextoDescripcion">_CentroExplotacion</span><span class="TextoValor"> *CentroExplotacion*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<br/>
<div class="InfoTarea" style="width:100%">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top">
                  _Asunto
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                 *Asunto*
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                 _Codigo
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                 *Codigo*
            </td>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                 _Solicitante
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                 *NombreSolicitante*
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                 _Ambito
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                 *Ambito*
            </td>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                 _Responsable
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                  *NombreResponsable*
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                  _Tipo
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                 *Tipo*
            </td>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                 _Grado
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                  *Grado*
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                  _Sub Tipo
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                 *SubTipo*
            </td>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                 _Prioridad
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                  *Prioridad*
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                  _Relacion
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                 *Relacion*
            </td>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                 _Estado
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="width:35%">
                 *EstadoTarea*
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%;margin-top:15px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%;">
                  _NumReferencia
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                 *NumReferencia*
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<hr/>
<br/>
    <div class="InfoTarea" style="width:100%">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top">
                    <span class="infoTarea">
                        _Solicitud
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10px;">          
                    *Solicitud*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top">
                    <span class="infoTarea">
                        _Descripcion
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10px;">          
                    *Descripcion*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top">
                    <span class="infoTarea">
                        _Informe
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                    *Informe*
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:auto">
                    <span class="infoTarea">
                        _ArchivosAdjuntos
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    *TablaArchivosAdjuntos*
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<hr/>
<br/>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top">
                <span class="infoTarea">
                    _Comunicaciones
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
            *Comunicaciones*
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><hr id="HRcomunicaciones"/><br/>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" style="width:99%" valign="top">
                <span class="infoTarea">
                    _OtrasComunicaciones
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                *OtrasComunicaciones*
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <!--  </table> --><hr/>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" style="width:99%" valign="top">
                <span class="infoTarea">
                    _textoCambioValidacion
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                *textoCambioValidacion*
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<!-- <hr/> -->
<!-- <div class="InfoTarea">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="TextoDescripcion" valign="top" style="width:15%">
                <span class="infoTarea">
                    _Solucion
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                 *Solucion*
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div> -->
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StylesReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="53f914b8-f951-4433-971d-6b1819430c56">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="htmlCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="742">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="742" uuid="8544346f-4c98-4069-a041-f6080a75e906"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RealSize" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Top">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA[$P{htmlCode}]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

And here the Java method for the exporting:

```
public String generarReportePdfAdjunto(String html, ArrayList<String> pathsImagenes){
        HashMap hm = null;
        String jrxmlFileName = "";
        String jasperFileName = "";
        String rutaPrincipal = "";
        InputStream reportStream = null;
        jasperFileName = "/frameHtmlv2.jasper";
        reportStream = funciones.class.getResourceAsStream(jasperFileName);             
        String pdfFileName ="*pathToPdf*";
        hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("htmlCode",html);
        hm.put("scaleType", "RealSize");
        // Generate jasper print, llena el report y renderiza el pdf
          JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream, hm, new JREmptyDataSource());
          JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, pdfFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html component (`hc:html`) uses the [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) to render the html as an image

As you can read in the documentation:

> HTML text. The kit used in this case is the class javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit which provides HTML 3.2 support.

also seen in these posts [Which HTML tags are supported in Swing components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872871/which-html-tags-are-supported-in-swing-components) and [Which HTML tags are supported in Swing components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872871/which-html-tags-are-supported-in-swing-components) you need to **use HTML 3.2**

*So whats wrong in my html?*

Using https://validator.w3.org selecting DOCTYPE 3.2, passing your HTML I get 31 Errors, 19 warning(s), [for example these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzw1c.png)

**Solution:**

Pass HTML that conforms to HTML 3.2